# How to test a matrix for inconsistency?

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand how to test two equations with two variables but what happens when I get up to 4 variables? I have no idea how to test that. For example with the matrix/system of equations

$x_1 +2 {x_2} + x_3 = 1$

$-2 x_1 - 4 {x_2} - x_3 = 0$

$5 {x_1} + 10 {x_2} + 3 {x_3} = 2$

$3 {x_1} + 6 {x_2} + 3 {x_3} = 4$

How do I find out if it is inconsistent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: take $-3$ times the first equation and add it to the fourth equation. The fourth equation will then become $0 = 1$, which is clearly inconsistent.

You can also express the system of equations as an augmented coefficient matrix, add $-3$ times row 1 + row 4 $\implies$ row 4 becomes $\quad0 \;0\;0\;|\;1$

Comment: But how do I know that it makes it inconsistent and that I just didn't mess it up? What if I didn't do that step and just did another? So should I start with guassian elimination?

Comment: See my edit: if you proceed with row-reduction, you'd eventually find an inconsistent equation. For example, if you took $-\frac 13$ times the fourth equation and added it to the first equation, the first equation would become: $0 = -\frac 13$. The point being, the first equation and the fourth equation cannot both be true $\implies $ the system of equations is inconsistent.

Comment: Ok thanks, I am new to this but what should I deduce if I get two identical rows? For example I have 3 rows and none are inconsistent but two are the same? I can see the answer in my book gives $x_1 = ...$ $x_2 = ...$ and $x_3$ is a free variable. If $x_2$ and $x_3$ have identical equation then is it okay to reverse them?

Comment: You'll learn that if you have two identical rows, the system would be dependent. Yes, you can reverse which is the free variable in the case where $x_2, x_3$ have identical equations.

Answer (score 2):

Try to solve the equation; and check whether the system has the solution or not.

$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 1 \\ -2 & -4 & -1 \\ 5 & 10 & 3 \\ 3 & 6 & 3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 2 \\ 4\end{pmatrix} $, and multiply first row by 3 and substract to 4th row then

$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 1 \\ -2 & -4 & -1 \\ 5 & 10 & 3 \\ 0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 2 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} $
which says that $0 = 1$ in the 4th row, which is inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way:

Add twice the first equation to the second to get $x_3 = 2$. Now substitute $x_3 = 2$ into the other equations to get $5 x_1 + 10 x_2 = 5 (x_1+2 x_2) = -4$ and $3 x_1 + 6 x_2 = 3 (x_1+2 x_2) = -2$, and you can immediately see that there is no solution.